Can't build ios with shared prefernces
The shared preferences plugin is not working on my Flutter App for IOS. Whenever I install the plugin in pubspec.yaml, and run flutter clean, flutter pub get and flutter build ios on cd ios directory I get this error.
**Parse Issue (Xcode): Use of '@import' when modules are disabled
/Users/ebenoasis/Desktop/hitchride/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:53:0


Semantic Issue (Xcode): Use of undeclared identifier 'SharedPreferencesPlugin'
/Users/ebenoasis/Desktop/hitchride/ios/Runner/GeneratedPluginRegistrant.m:66:3

Encountered error while building for device.**

But when I take it out it builds well.
What might be the problem?
This is the plugin I use   Shared preferences link

can you resolve it?
